# Why my PencilBlue Blogs are breaking? Word wrap not implemented?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pencilblue

I am very new to [PencilBlue](https://pencilblue.org/) and I have hosted my app on Openshift as documented.

I am trying to write down a page for this blog and the blog seems like this:

http://pencil-bhuwan.rhcloud.com/page/salesforce-bullshit

**The page is badly formatted and word wrap not implemented**. I thought that it'd be a problem with the theme so I tried DevBlog theme but the result was same.

I thought that I'd would be a problem on openshift so I tried to run it on my system. Sadly the results were pretty same.

Is there anything which I am doing wrong.  Why the word wrap is not working in PencilBlue. Or is this the right way it should work??

Note: I have not made any changes in code. The code is same as hosted on [this GIT repository](https://github.com/pencilblue/pencilblue).

Thanks.!

Comment: How would you know if word wrap was “implemented”? You don’t have any words. Try some nice Lorem ipsum.

Comment: Cool.! My BAd.! I tried it with some lorem Ipsum and it worked.!
http://pencil-bhuwan.rhcloud.com/page/test